# XPath queries to scrape data

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm using Copy XPath from Chrome to create my queries. It works very well but not for this question.

Here [is the site](http://www.di.se/di-fonder/fonddetaljer/?InstrumentId=1085603) I scrape data from.

One query that works (number next to "Senaste NAV-kurs" in table 1)

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.di.se/di-fonder/fonddetaljer/?InstrumentId="&1085603;"//*[@id='fund-summary-wrap']/div[1]/dl[2]/dd/text()" )
```

But when I copy XPath from table with title "AVKASTNING" i'm getting no data, pls help

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.di.se/di-fonder/fonddetaljer/?InstrumentId="&1085603;"//*[@id='ctl00_FourColumnWidthContent_ThreeColumnsContent_MainAndSecondColumnContent_fundInfo_fundPerformance_tableFund']/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to try it another way, the following will get the "AVKASTNING" table.

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://www.di.se/di-fonder/fonddetaljer/?InstrumentId=1085603","table",7)
```

If you want a specific value from the table use index. The following example gets the second row second column value:

```
=index(IMPORTHTML("http://www.di.se/di-fonder/fonddetaljer/?InstrumentId=1085603","table",7),2,2)
```

Comment: It works perfect with some small adjustment, some funds only have 4 tables and some 5. By adding a column with Table # and InstrumentID it is perfect!!